# Error while calling v1/audio/transcription openapi

Tags: javascript, openai-api

I have below code to convert a video to audio and then audio to text using OpenAI.

I have below code:

```
function transcribeVideo() {
  const openaiApiKey = api_key;
  const youtubeUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dT_aIJZ7Mxw';
  const videoFilepath = 'image.mp4';
  const audioFilepath = 'image.mp3';

  // Download video from YouTube
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(youtubeUrl);
  const fileBlob = response.getBlob().setName(videoFilepath);
  const folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  const file = folder.createFile(fileBlob);

  // Convert video to audio
  const ffmpegUrl = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Kagami/mp4-to-mp3@0.0.6/mp4-to-mp3';

  const response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(ffmpegUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    payload: {
      input: file.getUrl(),
      output: audioFilepath,
      '-f': 'mp3'
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true // use this option to examine the full response
  });
  
  const audioBlob = response2.getBlob();
  folder.createFile(audioBlob).setName(audioFilepath);


  // Transcribe audio to text using OpenAI
  const audioFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(audioFilepath).next();

  const blob = audioFile.getBlob().setName(audioFilepath);
  blob.setContentType('audio/mpeg');

  const formData = {
    'file': blob.setContentType('audio/mpeg'),
    'model': 'whisper-1',
  };
  const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${openaiApiKey}`
  };
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    payload: formData,
    headers: headers,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  const url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions';

  const response3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  const data = JSON.parse(response3.getContentText());
  const transcript = data.transcriptions[0].text;
  Logger.log(transcript);
}
```

While running this code, I am getting an error `Invalid file format. Supported formats: ['m4a', 'mp3', 'webm', 'mp4', 'mpga', 'wav', 'mpeg'`

I believe there is some issue with the audio file format. Is there anything that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You are using '-f', why don't you try 'response_format'